# SSH config /localhost and remote?

Tags: ssh, configuration

I've read on ssh, and I have my setup to use ssh with OpenWrt, I use key in .ssh + my config file in .ssh but if I want to use also ssh server as localhost, what I've read is that I should setup also in .ssh/config.

I'm not sure how to use both?

could you help me?
thank you

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear; is English your second language? After some thought I *think* you're asking how to set up `ssh` to act as a server as well as a client, in which case @telcoM 's answer has part of what you need.

Comment: Second language yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.ssh/config` in your home directory has normally nothing to do with the SSH server (`sshd`), only with the SSH client.

The SSH server will normally read `.ssh/authorized_keys` under your home directory if it exists. This pathname can be changed in the system-wide SSH server configuration file (usually `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, although that is also changeable when building the SSH suite from source code).

Answer (score 1):

As telcoM points out in their answer, you're conflating two separate (but related) concepts: An ssh *client* that you configure in ~/.ssh/config and can be used to connect to other systems with SSH -- and an ssh *server* that will listen on the SSH port to incoming connections so you can connect to your system from remote via SSH.

In most modern linux distributions, these two are packaged separately, generally named `openssh-client` and `openssh-server` but for the exact package names you'll have to consult the package manager of your distribution for the package name and then install it.

The good news is that said package should come with a config in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` that should already allow for external access in most normal circumstances; configuring it to secure it for your personal preferences is beyond the scope of this question.